# Scramble array in C?

Tags: c, random

I have a 2d array of coordinates, and I want to iterate through them in a random order. I am using `srand` so the coordinates will always be randomized the same with the same password. It is a form of security.
How can I scramble go through 2d array using `rand()`?

Comment: are you trying to just read the array, or move elements in the array?

Comment: @nycynik I'm trying to loop through it in a random (seeded) order. So just read it.

Comment: You can map 2d coordinates (i,j) into a 1d value `i*rowsize + j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple/easy way to do this is to create an array of integers from `0` to `n - 1` where `n` is the length of the first array.

Shuffle this array, and then use the values in it as indices for iteration over the original array.

There's no standard shuffle method in C so use this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Arrange the N elements of ARRAY in random order.
   Only effective if N is much smaller than RAND_MAX;
   if this may not be the case, use a better random
   number generator. */
void shuffle(int *array, size_t n)
{
    if (n > 1) 
    {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        {
          size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);
          int t = array[j];
          array[j] = array[i];
          array[i] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from: http://benpfaff.org/writings/clc/shuffle.html

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks. And I think you mean `n - 1`, not `1 - n`

Comment: Whoops, yeah. Fixed. No problem, glad I could help.